# Spinner in Button

Tags: jquery, html

I have a button like below.

```
<button type="button" id="#clock_in" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Clock-In</button>
```

How can I attach a `Spinner` after clicking on it and remove after an event using jQuery ?

I tried like below

```
$('#clock_in').click(function(e){ 
   $('.btn').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>Clock-In');
});
```

Comment: if you can explain more then will be helpful like where to attach or on which event you want to remove.

Comment: I would use `replaceWith` otherwise you could still reclick the button and submit again. If you are wanting to submit a form with this button, you would need tp prevent the default action of the button and submit the form using ajax, then in your callback function, you can then replace the loader with your button

Answer (score 2):

As per your question, I am guessing that you are going to use this with **Ajax** call.

For Spinner, here I am using **Fontawesome** library.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#clock_in").click(function() { 
  // Prevent from re-submit request by disabled button 
  $('#clock_in').attr("disabled", true);
  $("#clock_in").html('Clock-In <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin" id="spinner"></i>');
   $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function(data){
        //The Ajax request was a success.
        //Do something in here.
      },
      complete: function(){
        //Ajax request is finished, so we can enable
        //the button again.
        $('#clock_in').attr("disabled", false);
        $("#spinner").remove();
      }
    });
  }); 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Spinner Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 m-auto p-5">
      <button type="button" id="clock_in" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Clock-In</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

just from your description would be

```
$('#clock_in').click(function(e){ 

    $('.btn').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>Clock-In');



});
$(document).on(YOUR_EVENT_HERE, function(){
    $('.btn .fa-spinner').remove()
})
```

also, if you want to remove it after some animation you can try

```
$('#clock_in').click(function(e){ 
  var animationDuration = 2000;

    $('.btn').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>Clock-In');


   setTimeout(function(){
       $('.btn .fa-spinner').remove()
   }, animationDuration)
});
```